# Why does AngularJS throw an error when I try to build a URL for an iframe src attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been tinkering with AngularJS directives and I do not understand why my attempt to build an iframe src attribute with an expression is triggering an error. The thrown error references the following URL, but I'm afraid I don't find it very enlightening:

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$interpolate/noconcat?p0=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2F%7B%7BvideoId%7D%7D

What does that really mean and what can I do about it?

**Here are the relevant JavaScript and HTML:**

```js
angular.module("myModule", [])

 .directive("myDirective", function() {

  return {

   restrict: "EA",

   scope: {

    videoId: "@videoId",
    width: "@width",
    height: "@height"
   },

   // This seems to work as expected.
   //template: '<iframe width="432" height="243" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8aGhZQkoFbQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',

   // This seems to work as expected except for adding a little extra whitespace after the values.
   //template: '<iframe width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8aGhZQkoFbQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',

   // This throws an error that refers to http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$interpolate/noconcat?p0=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2F%7B%7BvideoId%7D%7D.
   template: '<iframe width="432" height="243" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{videoId}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',

   replace: true
  };
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<my-directive video-id="8aGhZQkoFbQ" width="432" height="243"></my-directive>
```

My thanks for any enlightenment.

**I am leaving the above in place for reference, but here is an edited version using a controller and $sce.trustAsResourceUrl as suggested in Muhammad Reda's answer in case it can help anyone to see it all together:**

```js
angular.module("myModule", ["ngSanitize"])

 .directive("myDirective", function() {

  return {

   restrict: "EA",

   scope: {

    videoId: "@videoId",
    width: "@width",
    height: "@height"
   },

   template: '<iframe width="432" height="243" src="{{srcUrl}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',

   replace: true,

   controller: function($scope, $sce) {

    $scope.srcUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + $scope.videoId);
   }
  };
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<my-directive video-id="8aGhZQkoFbQ" width="432" height="243"></my-directive>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your url needs to be wrapped around `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(YOUR_URL)`

[Documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ng/service/$sce).

Add a `controller` to your directive

```
angular.module("myModule", ['ngSanitize'])
    .directive("myDirective", function() {
        .....
        controller: function($scope, $sce) {
            $scope.iframeUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $scope.videoId;
            $scope.iframeUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.iframeUrl);
        },
        template: '<iframe src="{{ iframeUrl }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
    })
```

Comment: As it happens, I tried building the URL in a controller, but I was missing the $sce.trustAsResourceUrl bit because I didn't know how to use it. Thank you kindly for clearing that up.